# Running DSC in against azure windows vm using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, dsc

I simply want to run a configuration file or a powershell script against a windows vm using terraform.  I dont have a windows box. I dont want to use an automation account or use azure blob storage or whatever.

I just want to provide an inline script or a a uri to a script and configure the vm. You know how like aws lets me just...do userdata however I want? Yeah like that.

Can anybody link some comprehensible docs that put all of this together that doesnt assume I'm running windows?  With stuff like `type_handler_version` literally being random values to me I can't really make heads or tails of anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `Azure Custom Script Extension` which is similar to User Data from AWS EC2.
Terraform Azure provider has a resource for Custom Script Extension, named `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension`. The [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_extension#settings) itself for this resource provides a good example how to use it:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "example" {
  name                 = "hostname"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "hostname && uptime"
    }
SETTINGS


  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}
```

Obviously the `settings` part contains the scripts to execute. The structure of it is documented in detail on the [Microsoft Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows).

Comment: Yeah I saw that but there's really no real documentation whatsoever that actually defines what `typeHandlerVersion` or what it represents as those docs state `1.10` but the terraform docs state `2.0` and both are failing to be valid :/